# No CUDA-capable device is detected although requirements are installed

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

## Problem

I just installed `cuda` following the [official installations instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#abstract) via the `.deb` file. When it comes to [section 6.2.2.3](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#running-binaries) (running `deviceQuery`) I get the message that no CUDA-capable device was found although I'm pretty sure everything is setup correctly:

```
$ ./bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery
./bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

## System information

Here is some information about my system:

```
$ uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

$ uname -r
4.4.0-64-generic

$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I also verified the kernel headers are installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-64.85).
```

## Installation of CUDA

So my system meets all the prerequisites. I then followed the instructions for the [installation via apt-get](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation) (I installed `cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb`).

`PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are set to point to the required locations:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:[...]

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
```

Note that I did setup up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` manually although this was mentioned to be necessary only for the runfile installation. However the error persists when resetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The NVIDIA drivers also seem to be up-to-date:

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:37:01 PDT 2016
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

Information about the cuda compiler driver:

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

The instructions mention that this could be a problem with file permission:

> If a CUDA-capable device and the CUDA Driver are installed but deviceQuery reports that no CUDA-capable devices are present, this likely means that the /dev/nvidia* files are missing or have the wrong permissions.

Those files didn't have the execution flag which I then added:

```
$ ls -al /dev/nvidia*
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 195,   0 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidia0
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 195, 255 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidiactl
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 195, 254 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidia-modeset
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 243,   0 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidia-uvm
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 243,   1 Feb 27 18:24 /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools
```

However after running `deviceQuery` (which still fails) some of the permissions are reset:

```
$ ls -al /dev/nvidia*
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 195,   0 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidiactl
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 195, 254 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidia-modeset
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 243,   0 Feb 27 13:17 /dev/nvidia-uvm
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 243,   1 Feb 27 18:24 /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools
```

That's a bit puzzling especially because I'm running `deviceQuery` without `sudo`.

## Maybe related

### Samples build fails

When I try to build the cuda samples via `make` it fails for one of them with the message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'cudaDecodeGL' failed
make[1]: *** [cudaDecodeGL] Error 1
```

Which indeed seems to be missing:

```
$ ls /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libnvcuvid
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libnvcuvid': No such file or directory
```

Although the corresponding header file is there:

```
$ ls /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include/nvcuvid.h 
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include/nvcuvid.h
```

### Problem with static linking

The error which is raised from `deviceQuery` suggests a problem with static linking:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
```

AFAIK `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is only responsible for dynamic linking. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716293/trying-to-make-cuda-sdk-ld-cannot-find-library-ldconfig-says-it-can) where a suggestion is to include `/usr/lib/nvidia-current` to the linker path. However this directory doesn't exist within my installation:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/nvidia-current
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/nvidia-current': No such file or directory
```

Comment: looks like you are on a laptop, have you switched to nvidia using "prime-select nvidia"

Comment: As above... Nvidia drivers won't load if the card isn't being used. No Nvidia drivers, no CUDA.

Comment: Thanks guys, `prime-select nvidia` helped! I guess this means I was running on onboard graphics before?

Comment: @a_guest Yep, you were using your onboard graphics. To check what are you are using easily; after login > top right button > about this computer, you'll see your graphics there. Also could you select my answer so I'll get internet points and this question will be marked answered to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on a laptop with Nvidia Optimus, have you switched to nvidia using `prime-select nvidia`

Comment: I installed 'nvidia-prime' and ran the command. This seems to solved my problem with Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell server. 'It seems' because I haven't restarted the server, and I don't know if I have to run prime-select again.

Answer (score 2):

It should also be noted another potential cause of this behaviour is if the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable has been set to empty.

I experienced similar issues and it turned out this was accidentally getting set in my bash environment files.

Comment: A variant of this is if you have `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` set to the GUID of a card that you have replaced.